# how many sub-instructions are allowed in a transaction?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

So, how many sub-instructions are allowed in a transaction?

For example, I want to transfer 100 tokens to 100 different people and I wanna do it from a DAO multisig wallet - is it possible to do 100 subinstructions in an instruction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many instructions can I add to a single transaction?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2985/how-many-instructions-can-i-add-to-a-single-transaction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [size limit on solana transactions of 1232 bytes](https://solana.com/docs/programs/deploying). However many instructions you can fit in 1232 bytes would be the limit.

Comment: IIRC you can do something like this `transaction.serialize().length;` to calculate the size of your Tx. It can be helpful if you're debugging/trying to fix as much into a transaction w/o going over the limit.

Answer (score 0):

The other limitation is on the number of accounts.

From the [Solana docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#instruction-format),

> An instruction contains a program id index, followed by a compact-array of account address indexes, followed by a compact-array of opaque 8-bit data. The program id index is used to identify an on-chain program that can interpret the opaque data. The program id index is an unsigned 8-bit index to an account address in the message's array of account addresses. The account address indexes are each an unsigned 8-bit index into that same array.

Since account indexes are 1 byte, you can't have more than 256 accounts in a single transaction.